# SEF Joomla in Subdomain dan Subdirectory

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla

I Have Joomla website which located at `http://demo.mydomain.com/dir1/myjooma`.

I want to use SEF URL to make URL Friendly, but I always get 500 error. This is my .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On

  # Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]

  # Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]

  # Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]

  # Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})

  # Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
  RewriteRule .* index.php [F]

  RewriteBase /dir1/myjoomla

  RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The options directive may not be configured. I'd try removing `Options +FollowSymLinks` in the meantime.

Comment: still not work. is possible bug from template ? because I switch to default template, SEF are works